# How to create a loop with null in it

Tags: php, arrays, null

I am trying to create a for that runs when `$midarray[i]` isnt =`null`.

This is the script I created:

```
for ($i=0; $midarray[i] !=null; $i++) { 
    $maxarray = $i;
}
```

I am trying to do that as long `$midarray[i]` isnt empty, its will run the for.
I tried to use while but its didnt work.

Thank you!

Comment: So, what's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: You have to add "iterations limiting" condition as well: `for ($i=0; $i < $number_of_iterations && $midarray[$i] !=null; $i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the '$' for `$i`

```
for ($i=0; $midarray[$i] !=null; $i++) { ...
                     ^
```